# Mocking __init__ of a class imported in file

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a file copy_x_to_y.py which goes like this:

```
from abcd import F

def function_to_be_tested():
     F()
```

in abcd.py file, i have something like this:

```
from xyz import XY

class F():
   def __init__(self, arg1):
       self.xy = XY(arg1)
```

I want to mock **init** of XY in my test case.
I have tried mocking F's init with:

```
def mock_func(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

@patch('path/to/copy_x_to_y.F.__init__', mock_func)
def test():
    assert function_to_be_tested() is None
```

but it always happens to call XY's init, resulting in error as its initialization calls 
to connect with S3 with arg1. How to test this kind of structure?

Answer (score 5):

What is the reason for wanting to mock `__init__` of `XY`? Do you want it to return a specific object of XY, do you want to check if `XY.__init__` was called with specific arguments or something else?

A possible solution to your problem would be to mock the entire class, but have it return a "normal" object. Here's an example:

```
>>> from unittest.mock import patch
>>> class MyClass:
...   def __init__(self, val):
...     self._val = val
...   def foo(self):
...     print(self._val)
... 
>>> a = MyClass(1)
>>> a.foo()
1
>>> patcher = patch('__main__.MyClass', return_value=a)
>>> mock_class = patcher.start()
>>> b = MyClass(2)  # This will return a.
>>> b.foo()
1
>>> mock_class.call_args_list
[call(2)]
>>> patcher.stop()
```

Which in your case would be:

```
from xyz import XY
from path/to/copy_x_to_y import function_to_be_tested
def test():
  arg1 = ...
  a = XY(arg1)  # Has to be called before the patch to get a "normal" object.
  with patch('xyz.XY', return_value=a) as mock_xy:
    # Run funcion to be tested here and check results.
    function_to_be_tested()
    assert ...
```

### Some side notes:

1. It is possible to mock `__init__` directly though, if that's really what you need to do.

```
>>> def my_init(self, *args, **kwargs):
...   self._val = 1
>>> patcher = patch.object(MyClass, '__init__', my_init)
>>> mock_init = patcher.start()
>>> a = MyClass(2)
>>> a.foo()
1
```

2. If you use the patch decorator, you have to supply the decorated function with one extra argument that is the mock of the class or object.
   https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch

```
@patch('path/to/SomeClass', ...)
def test(mock_class):
...
```

3. Also patch is typically (exclusively?) used to patch a class while patch.object is used to patch a member inside a class or module. https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch.object

Comment: I came here looking for an answer to "check if XY.__init__ was called with specific arguments"; I guess side-note #1 would enable that, with `mock_init.assert_called_with(...)`.